# Persuading an email client not to display an html attachment inline?

Tags: php, phpmailer

Problem: I send out an email (using phpmailer and sendmail) which has a complex html attachment. I don't want the email client to attempt to display the attachment, since it's far too complex to be viewed in a mail reader.

As far as I can make out, the way to do this is to set `content-Disposition` to `attachment`. The default in phpmailer is to set it to `attachment` anyway. However, Thunderbird (the only client I've tested so far) does actually attempt to display the html. If I view the headers in Thunderbird, I can't see a `Content-Disposition`, but if I save the mail I can see:

```
--b1_420d367a26870bbc3bae73fb1de31f49
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="chart.html"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="chart.html"
```

Thunderbird has given the attachment the correct name, so it presumably understands the `Content-Disposition`. Is there something I can do with phpmailer to stop clients displaying html attachments, or can clients just do what they want?

Sending a compressed file isn't really an option - the users may not be sophisticated enough to know what to do with it.

Comment: Guessing: Thunderbird relies on file extension and file headers instead of Content-Disposition header.

Comment: Why not convert the content into pdf or an image. users just need to double click to open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> David :Bienvenu 2006-04-07 12:49:31 PDT
>   for historical reasons, this is done intentionally and has been since Netscape 2.0 and Mozilla 1.0...we display inline the attachments we know how to display unless you turn off view | attachments inline. Perhaps we could add a pref for respecting the content-disposition for all attachment types.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=147461

This has been a known behavior since at least 2002.  As far as forcing it to not be displayed inline, I'm not sure that it can be done except by the user setting a pref as mentioned in the bug report.

Answer (score 0):

How about saving it as pdf instead?

You can take a look at " [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)"

Comment: Can't do that - it's interactive.